# Convert int to raw data in python

Tags: python

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't find and answer.

How can I convert an integer to raw data?

Here's an example of what I'd like to do, convert `0x41424344` to 'ABCD'?

I know `chr(0x41)` = `'A'`, but what's the python way of converting an int to a full raw data buffer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3:

```
>>> (0x41424344).to_bytes(4, 'big')
b'ABCD'
```

In Python 2.x - you could use `struct`:

```
>>> struct.pack('>i', 0x41424344)
'ABCD'
```